# How to trace "out of memory" error from XCode based unit-test

Tags: unit-testing, xcode, memory

I am using XCode 3.0 with iPhone SDK and have a small iPhone application that includes a unit test for sqlite, however I get "out of memory" when I run it. How do I trace root cause of the error?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the simulator, where you can run the app on your computer. Or, if your phone is jailbroken, Install GRIP (Growl for iPhone). It has a built in Memory Watcher and it will tell you when your memory gets low. It can tell you exactly when the app runs out of memory.